# reading a greek character from a file

Tags: python, utf-16le

I am trying to read a line from the file ( in utf-16-le) that has a greek alphabet. here is the code:

```
f = codecs.open("dump.tmp", "r",'utf-16-le')
fr = f.readlines()
for line in fr:
    if line.startswith("MY LINE                     {u'\u03BD'<GEN>}"):
    gr = line.split("}")
    print gr
```

I do not get errors but nothing prints. So If I use the shell to print just say:

```
print u"\u03BD"
```

I am able to print this greek character. Am I doing something incorrect while reading the line?

I mean I tried sometime writing the character to the file and it worked. However, while reading the same trick does not seem to work.

Comment: do u want to print the value of that or '\u03bD'

Comment: No the line that I am reading has got the character and if I use the character directly in the above code it shows unicode error. That is why I was trying to read this by using HEX. Earlier I was able to write the greek characters. Somehow not sure if this works for reading as well.?

Comment: Are you sure the if clause is working? try dropping into a debugging session (with pdb, or any other debugging solution) and check if this is a logic problem and not a unicode problem (Although unicode is always evil, so I won't be surprised)

Comment: use UTF-8: it works i guess

Comment: Tried that no luck though.

Comment: have you tried just opening the file normally without encoding?

Comment: Ok I avoided the problem by reading only the first part of line and then extracting the character. Problem is solved now.

Comment: your problem is `畻尧ふ䈳❄䜼久紾`, that is not greek